# Keeping network data fresh in swiftui

Tags: swift, networking

I am relatively new to swift and am wondering how to keep my network data fresh over the lifecyle of a user session on my app.

I am hesitating to implement a function running on a timer that fetches data over the network every given interval, as I feel swift would have a more elegant way to handle this. However, I was not able to find any luck in searching for a comprehensive strategy in managing the refreshing of network data over time. Many of my users sessions last over a minute long and currently the data runs stale unless a specific event re-initializes a given view model.

Does anyone have a direction I can head in here? I would love a solution that is practical and one which I can build complexities upon as I grow, rather than a simple hack (which I believe the solution above may be). Please let me know, I would really love to figure this out.

**Update**

The app data is following:

1. user posts in which other users are specifically targeted (though the user gets a push notification while the app is in the foreground, the post they are being notified hasn't been fetched).
2. when a new user comes online, other users are not able to see them until they close and reopen the app
3. when a new chat messages comes in, the users have to exit and reenter the room to view new messages, which also messes with message sequencing (I am currently implementing a websocket solution for real time, but still am confused on how to manage messages over a longer lifecycle, and also message updates from rooms the user may not currently be in)

For the most part this is it. Architecting the messaging is a problem I am more than willing to take direction on if anyone is willing to offer it, as I am a little bit lost on what solutions to integrate ( between websockets, core data to persist messages without having to fetch full chats, and pagination to not fetch full chat rooms ).

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail on what your app does and what kind of data the users will be seeing? Hard to give guidance without this information.

Comment: @user1922718 just added update

Comment: You'll need to maintain an open socket with your server to handle notifications for users coming online, new messages, etc. The handler code in your client can call the appropriate function to download more information and update the UI as notifications come in.

Comment: You should look into [Viper](https://medium.com/@smalam119/viper-design-pattern-for-ios-application-development-7a9703902af6) this is a decent sample just know that what they call the View/UIViewController should be an ObservableObject in SwiftUI.